# retrieve value stored in certain bits of an int

Tags: java

We divided an int to save three values into it. For example the first 8 bits (from left to right) hold one value, the 8th to 12th bits hold another value and rest of bits hold the third value.

I am writing a utility method to get value from a certain range of bits of an int. is it good enough? do you have a better solution? **The startBitPos and endBitPos are count from right to left.**

```
public static int bitsValue(int intNum, int startBitPos, int endBitPos) 
{           
   //parameters checking ignored for now        
    int tempValue = intNum << endBitPos;
    return tempValue >> (startBitPos + endBitPos); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am sure all values will be unsign.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using an `int` this way, instead of storing each value separately in its own type?

Comment: Is that code correct? I wonder what happens with the sign bit.

Comment: The data is from hardware. They want to save space. All values are unsign.

Comment: The code is wrong in that case. You will return a negative value if the high bit is set in the top most left byte when you try to get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this isn't quite right at the moment:

- You should use the unsigned right shift operator to avoid ending up with negative numbers when you don't want them. (That's assuming the original values are unsigned, of course.)
- You're not shifting left by the appropriate amount to clear the extraneous high bits.

I suspect you want:

```
// Clear unnecessary high bits
int tempValue = intNum << (31 - endBitPos);
// Shift back to the lowest bits
return tempValue >>> (31 - endBitPos + startBitPos);
```

Personally I'd feel more comfortable with a mask-and-shift than this double shifting, but I'm finding it hard to come up with something as short as the above.

Comment: That code isn't correct. It's returning the wrong result for e.g bitsValue(0x80000001, 24, 32);

Comment: @Kaj: How can endBitPos be 32? That's off the end of a 32-bit integer. I'm assuming they're 0-based bit numbers, both inclusive. However, there was an incorrect sign. `bitsValue(0x80000001, 24, 31)` now returns 128, which is what I would expect. To make `endBitPos` exclusive, you can just change the 31s to 32.

Comment: That's the question, should it be inclusive or exclusive? Returning 128 for `bitsValue(0x80000001, 24, 31)` is probably correct. The method probably needs to be javadoc:ed. It's very confusing to have start bit read right to left.

Comment: @Kaj: Not in my view - bit 0 is pretty much always the least significant bit when labelling bits.

Comment: Bit 0 is also always lsb to me as well, but I read from left to right, so I would say that start bit is 31, and end bit is 24. That's why I want javadoc on that method. I don't think I'm the only one who would have used it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int bitsValue(int intNum, int startBitPos, int endBitPos) 
{           
    int mask = ~0; //or 0xffffffff
    //parameters checking ignored for now        
    mask = ~(mask<<(endBitPos)) & mask<<startBitPos
    return intNum & mask;
}
```

however if you have commonly used bitranges it's better to keep masks for them statically

```
0xff000000 // is the 8 most significant bits  
0x00e00000 // is the next3 bits and  
0x001fffff // are the remaining 21 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a couple of fixed length 'masks' you could store them explicitly and use them like this:

```
int [] masks = new int [4];
int masks[0] = 0x11111111;
int masks[1] = 0x111100000000;
// ...

public int getValue(int input, int mask){
    return input & masks[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that that code is correct (if I have understood the question). He wants to get the actual value that the bits represents, and that means that you have to shift them down (and take care of the sign bit)

Comment: You're right @Kaj . If that is the case one would also need to store a number for each mask of how far one has to shift down a value to get the right result.